# How to assign a remote public ip (via wireguard) to lxc container

Tags: linux, lxc, wireguard

What I have:

**lxc host**

```
# ifconfig
wg1: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 192.168.7.2
...

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.1.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
...

lxdbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 10.7.56.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
...
```

/etc/wireguard/wg1.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = my_private_key
Address = 192.168.7.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = my_public_key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = my_remote_server_ipv4:51194
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.7.56.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxdbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg1
```

**lxc container**

```
# curl ifconfig.me
my_remote_server_ipv4
```

Everything is ok, but:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 10.7.56.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.7.56.255
...
```

What I want:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet my_remote_server_ipv4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast ...
...
```

I want to do this without changing anything in the container.

*Upd.* I want to assign a public ip (owned by my remote server) to my home lxc container. Looks like it's impossible...

Comment: The answer to that is "you don't". Your "remote public IP" identifies whatever (a VM, probably) is running with that IP, on whatever provider routes to this IP. You can run a wireguard endpoint in this VM, and some kind of frontend process that forwards to your LXC container, but you can't "assign the IP". (Of course, if the LXC container runs on your provider's hardware, you can use whatever tools your provider gives you to make this container reachable on the "remote public IP, but from your description so far it looks like this is not your situation).

Comment: Please also read up on [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Your Y is "I want to assign the remote IP to my container", but we don't know your X (probably you want to run some kind of service on the container), and we don't know the rest of your setup (e.g. where the remote IP as actually assigned).

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: In your previous question you had 10 such remote IP addresses. Now only 1. As a *2nd one* should be used , this question is again incomplete. As long as you don't describe in details all your network setup with schematics and addresses, not much can be done. Btw, you're using LXD (not just LXC). If integration is to be done (rather than manual settings), that's a new layer of difficulty.

Comment: @A.B Thank you, the full picture here -https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654128/how-to-route-lxc-container-traffic-through-wireguard-tunnel. I tried to understand where I use LXD, but did not find it, it seems like everywhere LXC.