# How to route LXC container traffic through Wireguard tunnel?

Tags: linux, networking, lxc, wireguard

[image]
The image shows a complete picture of what I'm building. But for now I want to implement a small part with one home server and 2 LXC, 2 ipv4 on a remote server.
I want to use 2 different Wireguard tunnels for 2 LXC containers.
It's easy to solve when I have only one Wireguard tunnel - just "AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0" and all (host and guests) traffic will go thought Wireguard tunnel. But how to solve it in case of many different Wireguard tunnels?

**Home server 1**

WireGuard config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = my_private_key
Address = 192.168.7.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = my_public_key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 <- ok for 1 LXC, but how to do it for 2?
Endpoint = 11.11.11.1:51194
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.7.56.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxdbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg1
```

**Remote server**

/etc/wireguard/helper/add-nat-routing.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
IPT="/sbin/iptables"

IN_FACE="eth0"                   
WG_FACE="wg1"                    
SUB_NET="192.168.7.0/24"         
WG_PORT="51194"                  

## IPv4 ##
$IPT -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s $SUB_NET -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD 1 -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD 1 -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -i $IN_FACE -p udp --dport $WG_PORT -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 11.11.11.1 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.7.2
```

/etc/wireguard/wg1.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.7.1/24
ListenPort = 51194
PrivateKey = private_key
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/helper/add-nat-routing.sh

[Peer]
PublicKey = public_key
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.2/32
```

Comment: your wireguard config doesn't describe any of the wireguard endpoints in your picture, so I guess that's a source for confusion. Where exactly do you mean to have that wg1.conf?

Comment: @MarcusMüller updated, it's Home server 1, thanks.

Comment: Home server 1 itself doesn't have a wireguard tunnel in your picture. The LXC network namespaces do. And it makes no sense that the endpoint has an IP address from the internal wireguard subnet.

Comment: yes, the diagram is not very accurate, I tried to do it simply...

Comment: hm in this case I'd call it misleading then. We have no idea what networks you want to have, where.

Comment: I want my LXC home containers to be fully usable like a regular containers like DigitalOcean. With the configs that I specified it works as it should, but only for one container...

Comment: what difference does that make (there's nothing more "regular" about a commerically run container on a server somewhere else)? Well your picture shows one tunnel from each of the containers, is that what you want or not?

Comment: Difference between DO and my home servers? price and fun :)

_"Well your picture shows one tunnel from each of the containers, is that what you want or not?"_

Yes, but the tunnel is not from containers, but through the host machine (home server) from containers. I mean I want to do everything from the host without modifying the containers from the inside.

Comment: OK: your picture really is misleading then. Still, it makes no sense the endpoint's IP is from a private network (11.11...), that can't work; it needs to be the public IP address of the remote server.

Comment: sorry, why from private network? 11.11.11.1 - it's a public IP

Comment: It's a public, but a network assigned to the DOD, and is commonly used as internal network. But if that's a public IP address, why do all your containers get (expensive) public IPv4 addresses? that sounds less than desirable if you have a tunnel.

Comment: Each container will be an independent web service with its own external IP and its own open ports.